# how to create a back button in ios that goes to previous screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, side-menu

I have an app that has a menu. Please check attached image below:

[image: Menu Open]

Now if I go to "Council" under "Municipality" which is a page. It gives me a screen with text and on the upper bar I have a back button.
The problem is that when I click on the back button, it brings me back to the home screen. I need it to bring me back to the same menu open position where I originally tapped on the menu item.
How to make this possible?
[image: Council screen]

[image: Home Screen]

Comment: how did you have created this side menu ? Is this any library ?

Comment: @TooFast you should manage the navigation of screen with navigation controller..

Comment: @vikramsingh can you please give me more details? So far, whenever I click on the back button, it takes me to previous screen. For example, when I click on "Discover Aaqoura" ---> "Identity of Aaqoura" --> "Location" and while i'm in the "location" screen, if I click back, it takes me to the previous screen without issues only if I access this path through the blue horizontal menu bar. but when I access it from the 3 white lined navigation menu, then it puts me back to the home screen with menu closed whenever I click on back..

Comment: It is your requirement issue; you should first understand the navigation controller and its working "https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html". once you will understand the concept you will be able to manage it by yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using UINavigationController use this:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
  navController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

If you are presenting a view controller modally use this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil
```

If you want to pop to `rootViewController` (First view in navigation stack) use this:

```
if let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as? 
   UINavigationController {
   navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

If you are using any pod/library for side menu use their documentation or provide details in question so that we can help.